# In Vim, how to convert multiline to oneliner

Tags: vim

I have this text:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    culmus \
    fonts-beng \
    fonts-hosny-amiri \
    fonts-lklug-sinhala \
    fonts-lohit-guru \
    fonts-lohit-knda \
```

I would like it to be:

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends culmus fonts-beng fonts-hosny-amiri fonts-lklug-sinhala fonts-lohit-guru fonts-lohit-knda
```

from within Vi, and it can be in several commands. It doesn't have to be one complex command.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try `%s/\s*\\\n\s*/ /g` (although you don't need the flag `g` here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is get rid of the backslashes, new-lines and the leading spaces.  The easiest way to do this in Vim is with a regular expression substitution.

```
:%s@\\\n\s*@@
```

Explanation:

```
:%    " Over the whole file
s     " Perform a substitution (:help :s) s@search@replace@
@     " This is a delimiter: you can choose different symbols, but I 
      " picked @ here as I think it's clearer to see with all the backslashes
      " (:help pattern-delimiter)
\\    " Backslashes need to be escaped, so \\ means match a single backslash
\n    " Match a new-line (note that if this is in the replace bit of the
      " search-and-replace, you'd use \r)
\s*   " Match zero or more spaces (:help /character-classes and :help /star)
@     " Repeat of the delimiter to end the search part of search-and-replace
      " Nothing between the delimiters as we're replacing with nothing
@     " Another delimiter to end the replace part of search-and-replace
```